# Why can I not adjust the point color? It just goes black

Tags: graphics

Here is my code here.

Please help me correct this.

**How to make these 2 points Blue and Orange respectively?**

```
Manipulate[
 pp = ParametricPlot[{{r1 Cos[Min[w1 x, 2 Pi]], 
     r1 Sin[Min[w1 x, 2 Pi]]},
    {r1 Cos[w1 x] + r2 Cos[w2 x], r1 Sin[w1 x] + r2 Sin[w2 x]}},
   {x, 0, t}, PlotRange -> 10 {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, 
   AxesLabel -> {"Time"},
   PlotStyle -> {Automatic, Red}, BaseStyle -> Thick];
 Legended[
  Show[pp, Epilog -> {Black, AbsolutePointSize[5], 
     Point@Graphics`Mesh`FindIntersections[pp[[1]]],
     PointSize[Large], {Blue, Orange}, 
     Point[{{r1 Cos[w1 t], 
        r1 Sin[w1 t]}, {r1 Cos[w1 t] + r2 Cos[w2 t], 
        r1 Sin[w1 t] + r2 Sin[w2 t]}}]}],
  LineLegend[{ColorData[97]@1, Red, Blue, Orange},
   {"Earth Trajectory", "Moon Trajectory", "Earth", "Moon"},
   Joined -> {True, True, False, False}, 
   LegendMarkers -> {None, None, "Point", "Point"}]],
 {pp, None},
 {{t, 1, "Time"}, 0.01, 10 Pi, 0.01},
 {{w1, 1, "Angular Velocity"}, 0.2, 5, 0.01},
 {{r1, 2, "Radius"}, 0.2, 10, 0.01},
 {{w2, 1, "Moon Angular Velocity"}, 0.2, 5, 0.01},
 {{r2, 2, " Moon Radius"}, 0.2, 10, 0.01},
 TrackedSymbols :> {t, w1, r1, w2, r2}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use

```
Epilog -> {Black, AbsolutePointSize[5], 
  Point@Graphics`Mesh`FindIntersections[pp[[1]]], PointSize[Large], 
  Blue, Point[{r1 Cos[w1 t], r1 Sin[w1 t]}],
  Orange, Point[{r1 Cos[w1 t] + r2 Cos[w2 t], r1 Sin[w1 t] + r2 Sin[w2 t]}]}
```

or

```
Epilog -> {Black, AbsolutePointSize[5], 
  Point@Graphics`Mesh`FindIntersections[pp[[1]]], PointSize[Large], 
  Thread[{{Blue, Orange}, Point /@ {{r1 Cos[w1 t], r1 Sin[w1 t]},
       {r1 Cos[w1 t] + r2 Cos[w2 t], r1 Sin[w1 t] + r2 Sin[w2 t]}}}]}
```

to get

[image]